# Serializing a JSON object for a Django URL

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

I have a JSON object that looks like this:

```
var obj = {  
   "selection":[  
      {  
         "author":"John Doe",
         "articles":[  
            "Article One",
            "Article Two"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to pass this object to Django to render a view that displays 'Article One' and 'Article Two' upon render. I first serialize the JSON object so that it can be appended to a URL; I use `$.param(obj)` for serialization. Now the JSON object looks something like this:

```
"selection%5B0%5D%5Bauthor%5D=John+Doe&selection%5B0%5D%5Barticles%5D%5B%5D=Article+One&selection%5B0%5D%5Barticles%5D%5B%5D=Article+Two"
```

Now I can append this to a path and use `window.open(url)` the view will handle everything else. On the Django end, I was surprised to see that the structure of the JSON object has changed to this:

```
"selection[0][author]=John+Doe&selection[0][articles][]=Article+One&selection[0][articles][]=Article+Two"
```

I want to be able to use the JSON object as a dict e.g.:

```
obj = request.GET.get('selection')
obj = json.loads(obj)
print(obj[0].author)
...
```

How should I handle this JSON structure on the Django side of things?

Comment: I may be off the target here. But can you not use `JSON.stringify` and then encode it and send to the view?

Comment: @dunder You are on point. I completely missed `encodeURIComponent()` because I thought `$.param()` was the only way to go.

Comment: cool. Any particular reason why you are using a `json` in a `GET` call? As in, the same thing can be achieved with parameters `author` and `articles` right?

Comment: @dunder At some point I need to render a view with different articles by different authors e.g. John Doe (Article One, Two) and Jane Doe (Article Three, Four) so I figured a `JSON` object would be the one of the ways (if not the only way) to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not properly serializing the object to JSON, even if you say you do. The correct way would be to use `JSON.stringify()`, as @dunder states.

Than you parse it back to an object with `JSON.parse(strignifiedJson)`.

```
var obj = {  
   "selection":[  
      {  
         "author":"John Doe",
         "articles":[  
            "Article One",
            "Article Two"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
// Stringify and encode
var objAsParam = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(obj));

// Send as a param, for example like http://example.com?obj=YourStringifiedObject...

// Parse it back:
var parsedObj = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(objAsParam));
```

Comment: `encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(obj))` did the trick for me. I also realised that I should add the parameter to the URL i.e. `'.../?selection=' + <encoded_json>`.